# Plotting longitudinal data using loess smoother

Tags: r, plot

I need to plot a set of smoothed trajectories for individuals in a longitudinal (person-period) dataset. I can plot the individual trajectories across days using OLS regression but I would like to know how to plot the trajectories using a non-parametric smoother.

Sample data below. Same outcome variable measured five times for each individual at ages eleven, twelve, thirteen, fourteen and fifteen. Exposure is a predictor variable but we are not interested in it for this exercise.

```
id <- c(9, 45, 268, 314, 442, 514, 569, 624, 723, 918, 949, 978, 1105, 1542, 1552, 1653)
eleven <- c(2.23, 1.12, 1.45, 1.22, 1.45, 1.34, 1.79, 1.12, 1.22, 1.00, 1.99, 1.22, 1.34, 1.22, 1.00, 1.11)
twelve <- c(2.23, 1.12, 1.45, 1.22, 1.45, 1.34, 1.79, 1.12, 1.22, 1.00, 1.99, 1.22, 1.34, 1.22, 1.00, 1.11)
thirteen <- c(1.90, 1.45, 1.99, 1.55, 1.45, 2.23, 1.90, 1.22, 1.12, 1.22, 1.12, 2.12, 1.99, 1.99, 2.23, 1.34)
fourteen <- c(2.12, 1.45, 1.79, 1.12, 1.67, 2.12, 1.99, 1.12, 1.00, 1.99, 1.45, 3.46, 1.90, 1.79, 1.55, 1.55)
fifteen <- c(2.66, 1.99, 1.34, 1.12, 1.90, 2.44, 1.99, 1.22, 1.12, 1.22, 1.55, 3.32, 2.12, 2.12, 1.55, 2.12)
exposure <- c(1.54, 1.16, 0.90, 0.81, 1.13, 0.90, 1.99, 0.98, 0.81, 1.21, 0.93, 1.59, 1.38, 1.44, 1.04, 1.25)

df <- data.frame(id, eleven, twelve, thirteen, fourteen, fifteen, exposure)
```

Now we convert the person-level dataset to a person-period (i.e. long) dataframe and add a time variable

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)

dfPP <- melt(df, measure.vars = c("eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen"), var = "age", value.name = "score")

dfPP <- dfPP[order(dfPP$id), ]

dfPP$time <- rep(0:4, 16)
```

We can plot the raw data using an interaction plot

```
interaction.plot(dfPP$age, dfPP$id, dfPP$score)
```

but what we really want are lines of best fit for each individual

```
fit <- by(dfPP, dfPP$id, function (bydata) fitted.values(lm(score ~ time, data = bydata)))
fit <- unlist(fit)


interaction.plot(dfPP$age, dfPP$id, fit, xlab = "age", ylab = "score")
```

It would also be good to plot the average change trajectory across subjects

```
ints <- by(dfPP, df$id, function (data) coefficients(lm(score ~ time, data = data))[[1]]) 
ints1 <- unlist(ints)


slopes <- by(dfPP, dfPP$id, function (data) coefficients(lm(score ~ time, data = data))[[2]])
slopes1 <- unlist(slopes)
```

so to plot the mean trajectory we use an abline, superimposed over the existing graph

```
abline(a = mean(ints1), b = mean(slopes1), lwd = 2, col = "red")
```

Now this is all fine but does anyone know how to achieve a similar result except using a non-parametric smoother? Also with an average trajectory line superimposed. Using some kind of loess function perhaps?